# The target entry-point "@angular/core" has missing dependencies: - rxjs - rxjs/operators

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular10, angular-migration

Below is my angular environment details and other dependencies.Getting entry point error for angular-core when trying to migrate angular version.

```
Angular Version:10.2.5
Angular CLI:10.2.4
Node Version:14.20.1
```

```
Package.json
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "10.2.5",
"@angular/cdk": "10.2.7",
"@angular/common": "10.2.5",
"@angular/compiler": "10.2.5",
"@angular/core": "10.2.5",
"@angular/forms": "10.2.5",
"@angular/material": "10.2.7",
"@angular/platform-browser": "10.2.5",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "10.2.5",
"@angular/platform-server": "10.2.5",
"@angular/router": "10.2.5",
"@highcharts/map-collection": "^1.1.3",
"@types/proj4": "^2.5.0",
"angular-dual-listbox": "^4.7.0",
"angular-gridster2": "^3.19.0",
"angular-svg-round-progressbar": "^5.0.2",
"angular2-infinite-scroll": "^0.3.5",
"angular2-multiselect-dropdown": "^4.2.1",
"angular2-qrcode": "^2.0.3",
"canvasjs": "^1.8.1",
"chart.js": "^2.8.0",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"crypto-js": "^3.1.9-1",
"event-source-polyfill": "^1.0.22",
"flag-icon-css": "^3.3.0",
"highcharts": "5.0.14",
"jspdf": "^2.3.0",
"jspdf-autotable": "^3.5.14",
"keycloak-js": "^4.3.0",
"material-design-icons": "^3.0.1",
"moment": "^2.29.1",
"moment-timezone": "^0.5.31",
"nearley": "^2.19.7",
"ng-multiselect-dropdown": "^0.2.14",
"ng2-charts": "^2.2.2",
"ng2-pdf-viewer": "5.3.0",
"ngx-bootstrap": "^5.6.2",
"ngx-pagination": "^5.1.1",
"ngx-quill-editor": "^2.2.2",
"ngx-skeleton-loader": "^2.9.1",
"ngx-spinner": "^10.0.1",
"ngx-toastr": "^12.0.0",
"numeral": "^2.0.6",
"proj4": "^2.5.0",
"rxjs": "^6.5.3",
"tslib": "^2.0.0",
"uuid": "^8.3.2",
"validator": "^11.0.0",
"xlsx": "^0.15.5",
"zone.js": "~0.10.2"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1002.4",
"@angular/cli": "10.2.4",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "10.2.5",
"@angular/language-service": "10.2.5",
"@schematics/angular": "^10.2.4",
"@types/crypto-js": "^3.1.43",
"@types/highcharts": "5.0.16",
"@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
"@types/lodash": "^4.14.162",
"@types/node": "^12.11.1",
"codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
"cpx": "^1.5.0",
"jasmine-core": "^3.99.1",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
"karma": "~5.0.0",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
"karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
"karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
"ngx-json-viewer": "^2.4.0",
"protractor": "~7.0.0",
"ts-node": "~3.0.4",
"tslint": "~6.1.0",
"typescript": "4.0.8",
"yaml": "^1.10.2"
}
```

I am trying to migrate angular version from 9 to 10 and facing this issue.Not able to figure out the exact issue.Tried multiple versions of Rxjs used by the libraries that are used in my project.Also tried the github and stackoverflow solutions to delete the node modules,package-lock.json and reinstalling the libraries again.Nothing helps me.Attached package.json file content for reference.

Comment: can you try npx install in the folder where package.json is located?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to stackoverflow, the problem looks like it is related to your rxjs package, as it seems that angular/core (which is using a package from rxjs/operators) is not able to use it, one thing  you can do is try to ```npm install rxjs@6.5.3``` just adding this comment as I am not particularly sure about the problem, please provide or copy-paste the line of errors you got when you try to do the npm install